# Find remote IP for [kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host]

Tags: linux, ssh, security

I'm seeing walls of logs like this in `/var/log/auth.log`. Every 2 minutes ten lines of the same message appears. I would like to know the remote IP that generated these messages.

I'm running on Ubuntu 19.10 (it's my remote workstation, just doing regular security checkups)

```
61094 Jan 25 22:44:01 localhost sshd[10390]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61095 Jan 25 22:44:02 localhost sshd[10408]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61096 Jan 25 22:44:02 localhost sshd[10433]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61097 Jan 25 22:44:02 localhost sshd[10437]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61098 Jan 25 22:44:02 localhost sshd[10441]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61099 Jan 25 22:44:02 localhost sshd[10446]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61100 Jan 25 22:44:02 localhost sshd[10450]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61101 Jan 25 22:44:02 localhost sshd[10454]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61102 Jan 25 22:44:02 localhost sshd[10462]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61103 Jan 25 22:44:02 localhost sshd[10466]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61104 Jan 25 22:46:01 localhost sshd[12501]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61105 Jan 25 22:46:01 localhost sshd[12528]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61106 Jan 25 22:46:01 localhost sshd[12538]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61107 Jan 25 22:46:01 localhost sshd[12542]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61108 Jan 25 22:46:01 localhost sshd[12546]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61109 Jan 25 22:46:01 localhost sshd[12551]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61110 Jan 25 22:46:01 localhost sshd[12555]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61111 Jan 25 22:46:01 localhost sshd[12560]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61112 Jan 25 22:46:01 localhost sshd[12564]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61113 Jan 25 22:46:01 localhost sshd[12568]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61114 Jan 25 22:48:01 localhost sshd[14371]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61115 Jan 25 22:48:01 localhost sshd[14390]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61116 Jan 25 22:48:01 localhost sshd[14414]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61117 Jan 25 22:48:01 localhost sshd[14418]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61118 Jan 25 22:48:01 localhost sshd[14422]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61119 Jan 25 22:48:01 localhost sshd[14427]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61120 Jan 25 22:48:01 localhost sshd[14431]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61121 Jan 25 22:48:01 localhost sshd[14435]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61122 Jan 25 22:48:01 localhost sshd[14439]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61123 Jan 25 22:48:01 localhost sshd[14443]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61124 Jan 25 22:50:01 localhost sshd[16489]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61125 Jan 25 22:50:01 localhost sshd[16512]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61126 Jan 25 22:50:01 localhost sshd[16530]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61127 Jan 25 22:50:01 localhost sshd[16535]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61128 Jan 25 22:50:01 localhost sshd[16539]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61129 Jan 25 22:50:01 localhost sshd[16544]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61130 Jan 25 22:50:01 localhost sshd[16548]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61131 Jan 25 22:50:01 localhost sshd[16552]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61132 Jan 25 22:50:01 localhost sshd[16556]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61133 Jan 25 22:50:01 localhost sshd[16561]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61134 Jan 25 22:52:01 localhost sshd[18480]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61135 Jan 25 22:52:01 localhost sshd[18491]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61136 Jan 25 22:52:01 localhost sshd[18518]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61137 Jan 25 22:52:01 localhost sshd[18523]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61138 Jan 25 22:52:01 localhost sshd[18527]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61139 Jan 25 22:52:01 localhost sshd[18532]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
61140 Jan 25 22:52:01 localhost sshd[18536]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
auth.log-20200126-1579968001                                                                   61140,1        99%
```

Comment: did you check /var/log/secure for login attempts?

Comment: @iBug Kindly let me know how did you fix this error ?

Answer (score 1):

Try running `tcpdump` on your `ssh` port:

`tcpdump -nn -s0 port 22`

If you are already logged in over `ssh`, exclude your source IP address (eg: 203.202.1.1) so you don't flood your terminal with your own traffic:

`tcpdump -nn -s0 port 22 and not src 203.202.1.1 and not dst 203.202.1.1`

You can also use Netfilter to log connections to syslog but keep in mind, a flood of connections can create enough load on your server that it becomes unresponsive so not something you want to run without putting some kind of logging limit on it (as shown):

`iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m limit --limit 4/min --limit-burst 4 -j LOG --log-prefix "SSH_NOTIFY: "`

This will drop a message in your syslog about the connecting host

Answer (score 0):

check the permissions on the / directory, should be something like

```
drwxr-sr-x    1 root     root           512 Feb 12 21:12
```